# What are the empty string matches in this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression:

```
'2nd, 2nd'.match(/(?:([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)*/g)
```

...returns the following matches:

```
["2nd", "", "", "2nd", ""]
```

What are the empty string matches?

Comment: Because `(?:([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)*` matches an empty string.

Comment: Use: `(?:([0-9]+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)+`

Comment: The first 2 empty matches are around the comma, and the next 2 are the end of the string. Because `*` matches zero or more. `+` may be what you need; it matches 1 or more.

Comment: Your zero or any `*` match empty string